# Minimum working example for Qiskit's AdaptVQE

Tags: vqe, qiskit

I am trying to implement a simple AdaptVQE in Qiskit. Following the documentation provided by [Qiskit](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stable/0.40/stubs/qiskit.algorithms.minimum_eigensolvers.AdaptVQE.html), this should be very simple:

```
from qiskit.algorithms.minimum_eigensolvers import AdaptVQE, VQE
from qiskit.algorithms.optimizers import SLSQP
from qiskit.primitives import Estimator
from qiskit.circuit.library import EvolvedOperatorAnsatz

# get your Hamiltonian
hamiltonian = ...

# construct your ansatz
ansatz = EvolvedOperatorAnsatz(...)

vqe = VQE(Estimator(), ansatz, SLSQP())

adapt_vqe = AdaptVQE(vqe)

eigenvalue, _ = adapt_vqe.compute_minimum_eigenvalue(hamiltonian)
```

I tried putting

```
hamiltonian = SparsePauliOp("ZZ").to_operator()
```

along with providing operators to the `EvolvedOperatorAnsatz`, but none of this worked.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There is some code in a unit test for AdaptVQE here - take a look. https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/blob/main/test/python/algorithms/minimum_eigensolvers/test_adapt_vqe.py Since you don't say what fails, nor do I see much in regards of setting up the ansatz and the operator pool it needs, that unit test should help you sort things.